# Roboto font is not working with html code

Tags: html

Updated:- 
Unable to use Roboto font in HTML. My HTML template looks as below:

```
<span style="font-size:18px">
<span style="font-family:robotocondensed-light">During a raid at the Civil     Supplies Corporation office in Raipur, Bhatt&rsquo;s diary was recovered; he was a     manager in the corporation </span></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xoowrod6/#&togetherjs=zThvvyGAln

Comment: why java, android and regex are in the tags?

Comment: maybe because he wants to do it in an Android App with java and tought that using regex would be nice ? xD

Comment: @forcewill yes kindly help me create that logic

Comment: After your edit i cannot understand what exactly you want first you asked about replacing the font-size size programmatically in Android  and had the tags Android involved now you're complaining about the Roboto Font not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can find **Roboto Condensed** in [Google Fonts Library](https://www.google.com/fonts).

And use it like this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And I updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoowrod6/1/).